# how to return when null cursor is found

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have the following code that is reading data from a SQLite db. I can detect the null cursor, but I do not know how to escape from it. I can not move the return statement to within the `if( result != null && result.moveToFirst()` statement.
I get the last two log lines then the program crashes

```
/CSV Import﹕ cursor index is NOT greater than 0
/CSV Import﹕ Null Cursor Found
```

Code:

```
public Equipment getEquipmentByID(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String SQL = "SELECT "+EQUIPMENT_TABLE+".*, "+LOCATION_TABLE+"."+LOCATION_NAME+" as locationName FROM "+ EQUIPMENT_TABLE + " " +
            "JOIN "+LOCATION_TABLE + " ON "+LOCATION_TABLE+"."+LOCATION_ID+"="+EQUIPMENT_TABLE+"."+EQUIPMENT_LOCATION+" " +
                    "WHERE "+EQUIPMENT_TABLE+"."+EQUIPMENT_ID +"="+id;

    Cursor result = db.rawQuery(SQL, null);
    result.moveToFirst();

    if(result != null && result.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.v("CSV Import", "Null Cursor not Found");
    } else {
        if (result.getCount()>0) {
            Log.v("CSV Import", "cursor index is grater than 0");
        } else {
            Log.v("CSV Import", "cursor index is NOT greater than 0");
        }
        Log.v("CSV Import", "Null Cursor Found");
    }

    Equipment equipment = new Equipment(result.getInt(result.getColumnIndex(EQUIPMENT_ID)), result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(EQUIPMENT_NAME)),
            result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(EQUIPMENT_MODEL)), result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(EQUIPMENT_SERIAL)),
            result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(EQUIPMENT_NOTES)), new Location(result.getInt(result.getColumnIndex(EQUIPMENT_LOCATION)),
            result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("locationName"))), new EquipmentType(1, "Undefined"));
    return equipment;
}
```

Comment: why do you log `null cursor found`? your cursor clearly is not null at this point.

Comment: why do you think that Cursor can be null?

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()), `moveToFirst()` will return false if the cursor is empty, otherwise true. So starting with line: `result.moveToFirst();` replace all with:

```
if(result == null) return null;

if(!result.moveToFirst()) {
    result.close();
    db.close();
    return null; 
}

Equipment equipment = new Equipment(result.get //.... and so on ....//);
result.close();
db.close();
return equipment;
```

Comment: There is nothing in the docs that says rawQuery will not return null.  I would be especially concerned about that if the query is not valid SQL.  If I was code reviewing this I'd tell them to put a null check in, in case there is a null return from rawQuery.  There's never anything wrong with defensive coding.

Comment: I suppose you are right. However, even when I am querying on something that is not SQL, I get an empty cursor, not a null one. Reading through the source I don't see how a null cursor could be returned.

Comment: Reading further in to source, cursor will never be returned null unless you have your own cursor factory. Even if you do, you should have it return an empty cursor - not null.

Comment: Reading further into source is implementation specific.  You shouldn't rely on implementation details like that.  The null check costs almost nothing, its far better to have it and not need it than to crash.

Comment: @GabeSechan Binghammer is right: returned Cursor will never be null, the sources prove it, also the javadoc doesn't say it can be null

Comment: @GabeSechan Weather or not you think the cursor can return null does not dictate if you should be a programmer or not. That is why we are not telling you to pick another line of work because you are wrong. In fact, I hope this is the first time you are saying that. That is giving a bad name to other genuine programmers.  Bottom line: We are both right. Cursor cannot return null. HOWEVER, it does not hurt to have a null check like you say.

Comment: @pskink  No, first code defensively.  Then do everything else.  Not doing that is the reason why so may apps crash and burn.  Please STOP trusting docs and sources and use common sense.

Answer (score 0):

result never is null, your code is wrong, this works fine for you

```
public Equipment getEquipmentByID(int id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String SQL = "SELECT "+EQUIPMENT_TABLE+".*, "+LOCATION_TABLE+"."+LOCATION_NAME+" as locationName FROM "+ EQUIPMENT_TABLE + " " +
            "JOIN "+LOCATION_TABLE + " ON "+LOCATION_TABLE+"."+LOCATION_ID+"="+EQUIPMENT_TABLE+"."+EQUIPMENT_LOCATION+" " +
                    "WHERE "+EQUIPMENT_TABLE+"."+EQUIPMENT_ID +"="+id;

            Cursor result = db.rawQuery(SQL, null);
            //result.moveToFirst();
    if(result.moveToFirst()) {
        //Log.v("CSV Import", "Null Cursor not Found");
    Equipment equipment = new Equipment(result.getInt(result.getColumnIndex(EQUIPMENT_ID)), result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(EQUIPMENT_NAME)),
            result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(EQUIPMENT_MODEL)), result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(EQUIPMENT_SERIAL)),
            result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(EQUIPMENT_NOTES)), new Location(result.getInt(result.getColumnIndex(EQUIPMENT_LOCATION)),
            result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("locationName"))), new EquipmentType(1, "Undefined"));


    return equipment;

}

        else
            {
Log.v("CSV Import", "cursor index is NOT greater than 0");
            //if (result.getCount()>0)
           // {Log.v("CSV Import", "cursor index is grater than 0");}
            //else
            //{Log.v("CSV Import", "cursor index is NOT greater than 0");}
            //Log.v("CSV Import", "Null Cursor Found");

        }
    result.close;

}
```